# How to get Order and OrderLineItem for a transaction using Connect V2?

Tags: square-connect

I am writing a wrapper to retrive transaction data for the Square Connect API V2. I am able to retrive the trasactions with Order data missing.
I am getting following response using All Transaction and Retrieve Transaction API:

```
{
  "transactions": [
    {
      "id": "mYziFkYv2QK7e2kb2vyIhegeV",
      "location_id": "75S3K9Z9KSVYK",
      "created_at": "2017-04-17T11:00:51Z",
      "tenders": [
        {
          "id": "2qeDw6CmCs299m9w0RY7KQB",
          "location_id": "75S3K9Z9KSVYK",
          "transaction_id": "mYziFkYv2QK7e2kb2vyIhegeV",
          "created_at": "2017-04-17T11:00:51Z",
          "amount_money": {
            "amount": 10000,
            "currency": "INR"
          },
          "processing_fee_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "INR"
          },
          "type": "OTHER"
        }
      ],
      "product": "REGISTER",
      "client_id": "75S3K9Z9KSVYK-a776-4377-84f5-75S3K9Z9KSVYK"
    },
    {
      "id": "UJsg9IdIv9WWvqT1h2VkbxgeV",
      "location_id": "75S3K9Z9KSVYK",
      "created_at": "2017-04-17T11:00:37Z",
      "tenders": [
        {
          "id": "UVuQghb8RTF8OUcmAsaXKQB",
          "location_id": "75S3K9Z9KSVYK",
          "transaction_id": "UJsg9IdIv9WWvqT1h2VkbxgeV",
          "created_at": "2017-04-17T11:00:37Z",
          "amount_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "INR"
          },
          "processing_fee_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "INR"
          },
          "type": "NO_SALE"
        }
      ],
      "product": "REGISTER",
      "client_id": "75S3K9Z9KSVYK-a751-4434-a041-75S3K9Z9KSVYK"
    }
]}
```

Is there any way to get order (line item) details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for itemizations, you can use the v1 transactions endpoints. 
See here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-paymentid